# Add string “Added Comment” from the mod dashboard into transifex

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/dashboard?filtered=false

> [image: mod dashboard]

The string:

```
Added Comment
```

Could you add this string into transifex, so we will be able to translate it?